# How to build a debug executable in Qt5

Tags: qt, debugging, makefile, qt5, qmake

Does anyone know how to build a Qt5 app in debug mode? In Qt4 there used to be a flag in the CONFIG var which generated a Debug Makefile, but it seems it's not working anymore.

I do not want to hack the Makefile to add debug symbols and remove optimizations, so which is the neat way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

qmake will (at least in my configuration) produce 3 Makefiles (Makefile, Makefile.release and Makefile.debug). You can use `YOURMAKETOOL debug` to build your debug build.

Comment: Do you use QtCreator or another IDE/console to invoke qmake?

Comment: For me using Qt 5.3 qmake generates 3 Makefiles (at least on Windows OS).